# Kaltura CE 4.0 - Playlist doen't work on iOS

Tags: ios, html, playlist

I've got a problem playing playlists with iOS: when the site loads I get a spinning gear and nothing more. The playlist plays smoother on a pc. If I embed a single video, iOS devices play it without any issue.
In html head this is the script I embed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5.kaltura.org/js" ></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>    
mw.setConfig('Kaltura.ServiceUrl','http://host');
mw.setConfig('Kaltura.CdnUrl','http://host' );
mw.setConfig('Kaltura.ServiceBase', '/api_v3/index.php?service=');
mw.setConfig('EmbedPlayer.EnableIframeApi', false );
mw.setConfig('EmbedPlayer.UseFlashOnAndroid', true );
mw.setConfig('Kaltura.LoadScriptForVideoTags', true );
mw.setConfig('Kaltura.AllowRemoteService', false );
mw.setConfig('Kaltura.UseAppleAdaptive', false );
</script>
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by new http://html5.kaltura.org/js version released by kaltura HTML5 community